# How to utilise watchdog or how to debug webform error

Tags: 7, debugging, civicrm, webforms

I have a webform that integrates into CiviCRM such that the webform is used to save data into the Civi system.  The following error is generated when hitting submit (although data is saved in the results tab of the form):

[image]

The lease helpful error message in the word - unless you only have one field =/

Any ideas as to how I can decipher which field is causing the issue e.g. use Watchdog or something to see what the query is or why the error is appearing.  I don't have access to the mySQL server logs.

Comment: Normally Apache errors log file should tell you where this issue is coming from. Usually, it is located in the following directory on your server.  apache/logs/error_logs

Comment: The easiest way to debug that is using Raven Sentry client module https://www.drupal.org/project/raven you will find what exactly the problem. I think it's in mapping fields based on your message.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking the time to looking into the issue Jay Chand and Ziftman.

Turns out that if you go into the admin panel in CiviCRM there is a debugging option where you can turn on callback on errors and thus gain more insight into error messages such as the one I mention above.